# Question about #1 and #2 (ALL) in the Nested SELECT Quiz from sqlzoo.net

Tags: sql, correlated-subquery

I'm a little confused by the use of ALL.In the Nested SELECT quiz from sqlzoo (link [here](http://sqlzoo.net/wiki/Nested_SELECT_Quiz):)

Q1: Select the code that shows the name, region and population of the smallest country in each region

```
SELECT region, name, population FROM bbc x WHERE population <= ALL (SELECT 
population FROM bbc y WHERE y.region=x.region AND population>0)
```

I thought this made sense to me, because we're trying to get the population that is less than the smallest country in each region (queried with the inner subquery first).

But then, Q2 comes along: Select the code that shows the countries belonging to regions with all populations over 50000

And then code for that is:

```
SELECT name,region,population FROM bbc x WHERE 50000 < ALL (SELECT population 
FROM bbc y WHERE x.region=y.region AND y.population>0)
```

If we're trying to get the countries with population > 50000, why is the sign not > but < instead?

I feel like I'm missing a basic understanding somewhere, but I'm not even sure where.

Answer (score 1):

It would more readable and easier to understand if it could be written like this:

```
WHERE ALL (SELECT population....) > 50000
```

but this is **syntactically wrong**. 
From https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/all-any-some-comparison-conditions-in-sql

> The ALL comparison condition is used to compare a value to a list or
>   subquery. 
>  **It must be preceded** by =, !=, >, <, <=, >= and
>   followed by a list or subquery.

Also from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/all-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017
the syntax should be:

> scalar_expression { = | <> | != | > | >= | !> | < | <= | !< } ALL (subquery)

so you can't avoid having the `ALL` clause at the right side of the comparison,
but it's all the same since `50000` must be less than every item in the subquery.

Answer (score 0):

For the first question, `population` is the first, so when you query "the population that is <= (less or equal to) all of the populations", it implies it's the smallest one.

In the second question, 50000 comes first in the comparison.

"Populations of over 50000" also implies that 50000 < those populations, which is exactly what it says in the query.